# Android in-App:how to store purchase details permanently?

Tags: android, in-app

i have included in-App purchase in my app where a  user can purchase 4 items..items in the sense validity period..Suppose a user buy one 3 months validity item, it has be showed to him like "3 months validity left', whenever he log in to the app..So what i am saying is how can i store these values with regards to each user ? Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user successfully purchases one of your items (subscriptions?) then you can store the date that the item will expire in the device internal storage or on a web server that serves your application. Whenever the user opens the app/goes to a certain activity, subtract the current time from the stored expiration date, and you'll have a value for their remaining time.

[Android Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

Comment: i have a function onPurchaseStateChange() once the purchase is done.There is a parameter  'purchaseTime'..Should i get date from this ?

Comment: Yes, that would be the most accurate as it is exactly when the purchase went through. Use that date, and depending on the itemId that they purchased, add the length of their subscription (in milliseconds) to purchaseTime. You now have the expiration date of their subscription. Ideally you should send this value up to a web server where it will be stored and linked to a user's account. Alternatively, just persist the data on the device using the link i provided above. The issue with this approach is that if they uninstall the app or clear the app's data, they will lose their subscription.